# A lambda expression with statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, lambda

```
            return _employeeRepository.Get().SingleOrDefault(employee =>
            {
                var mailPrefix = employee.LoginName.Split('@')[0];

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(employee.LoginName)
                    && employee.IsActive.Value 
                    && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(employee.AdGuid)
                    && string.Equals(mailPrefix, guestLoginName))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            });
```

Error: A lambda expression with statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree

Comment: Yep, that is an error message alright. And it's pretty clear too. What's your question? If you just want to "get rid of the error", ask your IDE to inline the `mailPrefix` variable and convert the `if` to a ternary expression; it should be able to do this on the fly. Note that this does not guarantee the resulting expression can be translated to a query, that's a separate problem.

Comment: Ad far as Entity Framework is concerned, this is a *complex* statement, which cannot be translated into equivalent SQL. Maybe you can remove the split and check that the email address starts with guestLoginName + "@"

Answer (score 1):

Separating your predicate logic for the employee to standalone bool method should work - a simple modification of the code:

```
private bool IsEmployeeLoginNameValid(Employee employee)
{
   var mailPrefix = employee.LoginName.Split('@')[0];

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(employee.LoginName)
                    && employee.IsActive.Value 
                    && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(employee.AdGuid)
                    && string.Equals(mailPrefix, guestLoginName))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
}
```

Then just use it like this:

```
return _employeeRepository.Get().SingleOrDefault(IsEmployeeLoginNameValid);
```

Or

```
return _employeeRepository.Get().SingleOrDefault(employee => IsEmployeeLoginNameValid(employee));
```

EDIT: If you .Get() return IQueryable, you will have to materialize the collection first in order to make my suggestion work - otherwise it could throw an error -> I guess you are using EF and standard queries via repository translates the LINQ to native SQL query. So any local method/expression will not work because the query provider will not be able to transform it to sql query.

Comment: I assume that this `.Get()` returns an `IQueryable<Employee>`. Your method call still isn't convertible to SQL so this will fail with the same error